# Ubuntu 16.04.6 Wifi not being detected on new HP laptop

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.6 for work on a new laptop. I can get internet through an ethernet connection, but there is no wifi being detected at all and no additional drivers to install. How can I get wifi on this computer? Complete Ubuntu beginner.

Here is the output of lshw -C network:

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:80500000-8050ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enx000ec656d745
       serial: 00:0e:c6:56:d7:45
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=asix driverversion=22-Dec-2011 duplex=full firmware=ASIX AX88772 USB 2.0 Ethernet ip=192.168.0.30 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

and here is the output of lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:c822]
    DeviceName: Realtek Wireless LAN + BT
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:85f7]
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: SK hynix Device [1c5c:1327]
```

***thank you any help would be greatly appreciated!!***

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: just added to the original post

Comment: The 10ec:c822 device is included in newer kernel versions in the driver *rtwpci*. What is your kernel version? `uname -r` Does it include the needed driver? `modinfo rtwpci` Does the driver load but require firmware? `dmesg | grep rtw`

Comment: My kernel version is 4.15.0-99-generic. It seems I dont have the rtwpci module ("modinfo: ERROR: Module rtwpci not found.") How do I download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-date update
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git -b rtw88
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtw_8822ce
```

Your wireless should now be working.

When your kernel changes, that is, when Update Manager installs a later kernel version, known as linux-image, then you need to do the following:

```
cd ~/rtlwifi_new
git pull
make
sudo make install
```

Remember, this MUST be done whenever you get a new kernel - no exceptions. Please retain the file and these instructions for this time.

Comment: Those commands worked, thank you!