# network UNCLAIMED : Lost Ethernet/WiFi drivers after updating to Ubuntu 16.04.6 simultaneously on 2 different computers!

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, network-manager, ethernet

Updated from 16.04.3 to 16.04.6 (over ethernet on one computer, WiFi on the other) and now no ethernet or WiFi, only the loopback.

I am flexible if the solution requires going back to 16.04.3. 
I have the same issue as [This Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227732/ubuntu-16-04-6-wifi-not-being-detected-on-new-hp-laptop), but was not able to attempt the solution (No ethernet, WiFi, tethering) is not possible to my knowledge.

To install the kernel 4.15.0-65-generic, I did the following:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-4.15.0-65-generic
sudo apt install linux-headers-4.15.0-65
```

Verify that the kernel is installed correctly

```
uname -r
   4.15.0-65-generic
```

Went into grub to select the kernel to be the default

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

changed `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to `GRUB_DEFAULT="1>4"` based on the syntax "menu > submenu"

Anytime grub is modified:

```
sudo update-grub
```

**Debug process thanks to the answers to this question:**

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
   03:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
   Subsystem: AzureWave AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2c97]
   04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0)
   Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1043:1487]

modinfo rtwpci
   modinfo: ERROR: Module rtwpci not found.

sudo modprobe ath9k
   modprobe: FATAL: Module ath9k not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-65-generic
```

After switching to a previously installed kernel (tap/hold shift during startup to get to the Grub menu, selecting Advanced options for Ubuntu) I resumed startup in 4.15.0-88-generic. In the terminal I ran

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
   linux-generic-hwe-16.04 is already the newest version (4.15.0.99.106)
```

Back in 4.15.0-65 now. Checking the status of the linux module

```
sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-4.15.0-65-generic | grep Status
   Status: install ok installed
```

Locating current ath9k drivers.

```
sudo updatedb && locate ath9k.ko

   /lib/modules/4.15.0-88-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
```

Therefore, ath9k is missing for 4.15.0-65.

I can post the same info for the second computer if required, but I am thinking the fix for this might also fix that one. Any insight would be awesome! Thank you.

Comment: The correct driver for your device is `ath9k` Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe ath9k` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you, I have made the edit. (FATAL: ...ath9k not found..)

Comment: @chili555 Kernel seems to be partially installed. `modiles` or `extra` is missing. How would you fix it without networking. Maybe USB tethering and `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04`

Comment: @ThreeSpaceTab What exactly  did you do to upgrade "from 16.04.3 to 16.04.6 "? This doesn't require anything special. Buit it looks like you did something wrong.

Comment: I actually didn't purposely do an update to .6. It must have happened during an apt-get install update / upgrade?

Comment: Whay is the response to the command: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-4.15.0-65-generic | grep Status`

Comment: 'Status: install ok installed'

Comment: Is 4-15.0-68-generic the kernel version you are booted into where the ath9k module is missing? `uname -r`

Comment: yes, (assuming you meant 4.15.0-65.)

Comment: Please let is see: `sudo updatedb && locate ath9k.ko`

Comment: I will add it to the question. ath9k.ko was not located for 4.15.0-65 but was for the other kernels.

Comment: As kernel version -88 is newer and presumably up-to-date and contains ath9k, why not just run -88 and ignore -65. In fact, from -88, you could simply remove -65.

Comment: That may be possible, however I am trying to learn what I did wrong with the install of -65.

Comment: How, exactly, did you do the update? Did Software Updater offer a newer kernel version, headers, linux-modules, linux-modules-extra and did you accept and install all of them with one click or did you download some but not all of the debs and install them yourself? Somehow, a step got missed. Frankly, I'd boot into -88 and ignore it altogether.

Comment: I updated the steps I took. You are correct I did a manual kernel download and missed some. It looks like I missed linux-modules-extra but potentially some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To install the kernel 4.15.0-65-generic, I did the following:
>
> sudo apt install linux-image-4.15.0-65-generic sudo apt install
>   linux-headers-4.15.0-65

In order to get the required kernel modules; that is drivers like ath9k, you also needed to install linux-modules-4.15.0-65-generic as well as linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-65-generic. It appears that this step was missed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I installed the two packaged and it solved my problem. You are awesome!

Comment: Glad it's working!

Answer (score 1):

You can always boot with a previous kernel using `grub` menu.

Your current kernel is partially installed for some unknown reason.

After you boot with a previous kernel the missing kernel modules should appear.

Then connect to the internet and run

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

Comment: I did recently change to the current kernel so that would make sense. I am not able to share a screen capture of it, but my Grub menu overlay didn't go away when I selected Advanced options for Ubuntu. (I know what the options are and navigated to another kernel, 4.15.0-88-generic). I ran 'sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04' 'is already the newest version (4.15.0.99.106)' I will add this to my question.